# Impedance Matching Tab in Altium Designer Stackup manager

Tags: altium, impedance, impedance-matching

do not see any Impedance Matching Tab in Altium, in our company it is Altium Designer 23 installed. Any idea, how to activate impedance matching?

[image: Stackup Manager]

Comment: Your design has no dielectric layers?  I'm... impressed, but I don't think that will fab very well.

Comment: @TimWilliams, the fab shop won't care so long as the laminate requirements are specified in a drawing or note somewhere. Even less if they're using a low-cost shop that just uses whatever FR-4-like material is on hand and adds up to 1.6 mm.

Comment: @ThePhoton Well that's the thing: assuming one generates such a drawing, this is the dialog in Altium from which it is generated. Whether the fab honors that, is indeed a different matter...

Comment: @TimWilliams, I've worked with shops that just wanted a text file to give the stack-up (years ago) and I've more often drawn the stack-up by hand in Altium rather than use Altium's autogenerated stack-up note/drawing. If you're just doing 4 layers with "as required" thicknesses, it's easy to draw (or cut and paste from the previous design).

Comment: thanks @TimWilliams, looks it is not in place exactly because of dielectrics not added, when I added dielectric layers, it is appeared

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for answers! @TimWilliams right:
Dielectric layers should be added, when I added them, Impedance Matching tab appeared
[image]